# What does [Structure pointer a = Structure pointer b] do?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I've only recently exposed myself to Linked Lists and i'm quite hopeless.
So anyway,i've given pieces of code below to make myself understood better.

```
struct node
{
    int item;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *root;
struct node *conductor;

root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

root->item = 777;
root->next = 0;
```

So my question is, What happens when i do: `conductor = node;`?
Moreover, is there a difference between:

```
conductor = node;
```

and

```
conductor = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
conductor->item = root->item;
conductor->next = root->next;
```

If there is a difference, what is the difference? and how would you go about to write an equivalent statement of `conductor = root;` ?

Comment: `conductor = node`??? What is that supposed to mean? You have no such line in your code. You have no variable named `node` in your program. So, what is `node`? You need to explain what you mean by `conductor = node` before anyone can meaningfully answer it.

Comment: node is the name of my structure.

Comment: Firstly, in C language name of your structure is `struct node`, not `node`. Two words, not one. Secondly, if `node` does indeed names a type, then `conductor = node` makes no sense at all. It is invalid. You are not allowed to use types as operands in expressions.

Comment: For the record,i didn't write the code,i was looking online for some simple code to teach myself Linked lists and i found this.
From the answer below conductor=node apparently does makes sense,it makes conductor point to the same address as node.Thanks.

Comment: The answer below makes a desperate attempt to invent the meaning for that `conductor = node`. It is a guess, since you provided no information. So, I'm just wondering maybe you can somehow provide an explanation for what `node` is. The explanation you provided in the comment above ("node is the name of my structure") actually directly invalidates your own question and the answer below.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ETbfRBVM  I've pasted the whole code in there

Answer (score 6):

```
conductor=root
```

makes `conductor` to point to the same address as `node`, while

```
conductor=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
conductor->item=root->item;
conductor->next=root->next;
```

creates a brand new copy. You could try

```
printf("%p %p", conductor, root);
```

to see the addresses they point to, or

```
node->item = 12345;
printf("%d %d", conductor->item, root->item);
```

to see if they *actually* refer to the same instance.

Comment: I've ran into a problem,i used printf(); to see if 
`    conductor=root;    `
and
`   conductor=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    conductor->item=root->item;
    conductor->next=root->next;    `
Produces the same result,and it does produce the same result,but strange enough my code doesn't seem to work when i do 
`   conductor=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    conductor->item=root->item;
    conductor->next=root->next;    `
Could you please explain? I have the whole of my code pasted here -> pastebin.com/ETbfRBVM

Comment: @himom You should create another question. Remember to explain what "doesn't seem to work" means in detail. What do you expect to happen? What happens now?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a pointer references an area in memory in which values are stored.  A pointer itself is a 8-byte integer (though the exact size is machine-dependent) that refers to a location in memory.  When we have a pointer to some type, the value of the pointer refers to the first byte of that type in memory.

When you initially declare a pointer, it has no meaningful value before you assign it (like all variables in C).  But to be useful, it needs to know where to point.  You can either ask the operating system to give you some memory to point to (via malloc), or you can point to something you already have by assigning it a memory address.

## Assignment

When you do `conductor=root`, you are copying the value of `root` (the memory *address*, not the memory itself) into `conductor`.  Since they both have the value, they refer to the same location in memory, so they both point to the same place!

This method makes a copy of the *pointer*, not the *structure*, so they both point to the same thing in memory.  Thus, if you where to reassign `root->item`, the value of `conductor->item` would *also change*.

Note that you have now given the same memory location two different names, which could be either very convenient or very frustrating.  This phenomenon is known as aliasing [(see Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)).  Use it with care!

## Malloc

When you call malloc, you ask the operating system to set aside some solid block of memory somewhere big enough to store the amount of data you request.  malloc does this, then returns to you the memory location (pointer) of the first byte in that block.  Thus, when you say `root = malloc(sizeof(struct node))`, you get back a pointer to a new block of memory large enough for one node structure.

When you do `conductor = malloc(sizeof(struct node))`, you are setting aside another, *new* block of memory and telling `conductor` to point to that block.  So in the first example, they're looking at the same place, and in the second example, they're looking at different places.

This method has the effect of making `conductor` point to a totally separate copy of the structure `root` points to.  If you reassign the value of `root->item`, `conductor->item` will remain unchanged.

Note that `conductor->item` in shorthand for `(* conductor).item`.  You first are dereferencing the `conductor` pointer to get the value stored in memory there (the conductor structure), and then accessing the `item` member.  When you do `conductor->item=root->item`, you are *copying* the value of `root->item` into the `conductor->item` variable, which is in the new memory block you malloc'd for `conductor`.  You are not changing anything about the `conductor` variable itself, just the memory it points to.

## Linked Lists

In the context of linked lists, you would probably want to do something like `root->next = conductor`.  This will make `next` point to the same memory location that `conductor` does, and therefore you can reference the values that `conductor` points to.  `conductor` could then have another pointer to node referenced in its `next` member, and so on for as many links in the list as you like.  Note that is is common practice to set the `next` value of the last link to `NULL`, so you know where the end is.

Answer (score 0):

its completely pointer concept .. i hope there is nothing to deal with Linkedlist.

```
conductor = node ;
```

above line is a pointer assignment. after this both pointers will pointing/refer same memory location.

```
conductor = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
conductor->item = root->item;
conductor->next = root->next;
```

here you are allocating memory to conductor.